# How do you solve these 2 equations?

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics, symmetric-polynomials

$$xy = 1/6$$
$$y+x = 5xy$$
I tried solving them using all methods - substitution, elimination and graphing - but can't get the solutions

Comment: What were "all those methods" that you tried?

Comment: Substitution, elimination and graphing.

Comment: Take the first equation and insert it into the second

Comment: Actually I can't use the graphing so what I meant was substitution and elimination.

Comment: Remember if the amount of variables and amount of equations are equal, you can always solve that system of equations. Just substitute the value of any one variable from one equation in another.

Comment: Can you show it to me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this equation by using substitution of variables.

Using the first equation $xy=1/6$, we can rewrite it as $y=\frac1{6x}$.

Plugging this in to the second equation, we get $$x+\frac1{6x}=5\frac{x}{6x}$$

Simplify the right-hand side to $\frac56$ and multiply both sides by $x$ to obtain

$$x^2+\frac16=\frac56x \ \ \ \ \to \ \ \ \ \ x^2-\frac56x+\frac16=0$$

Using the quadratic formula, we now have $$x=\frac{\frac56 \pm \sqrt{\frac{25}{36}-\frac46}}{2}=\frac5{12} \pm \frac12\sqrt{\frac1{36}}=\frac5{12} \pm \frac1{12}$$

Our solutions for $x$ are $\frac13$ and $\frac12$. Using $y=\frac1{6x}$, we get the coordinate pairs to be $(\frac13,\frac12)$ and $(\frac12,\frac13)$.

Comment: In the quadratic equation, it's easier to compute if we just first multiply both sides with $6$ to get $6x^2 -5x +1=0$, and get only integers to compute with. The determinant becomes $(-5)^2 - 4\cdot 6 = 1$ so we get a nice result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

\begin{array}{c}
   xy = \frac 16 \\
   x + y = 5xy = \frac 56
\end{array}

Let $x = \frac{5}{12} + t$ and $y = \frac{5}{12}-t$. Then $x+y=\frac 56$.

\begin{align}
   xy &= \frac 16 \\
   \bigg(\frac{5}{12} + t \bigg) \bigg(\frac{5}{12} - t\bigg) &= \frac 16 \\
   \frac{25}{144} - t^2 &= \frac{24}{144} \\
   t^2 &= \frac{1}{144} \\
   t &= \pm \frac{1}{12} \\
\end{align}

$\frac{5}{12} + \frac{1}{12} = \frac 12$ and $\frac{5}{12} - \frac{1}{12} = \frac 13$

So $(x,y) = \left\{\big(\frac 12,\frac 13 \big),\big(\frac 13,\frac 12 \big)\right\}$